# How tall can a building be on Earth?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, material-science

This is maths IA problem

Here I have no idea how to solve this problem so any kind of help or suggestions invited

how tall can a building be on earth?

Comment: I guess, like, 1000 parsecs, depending on potential future materials, of course

Comment: Even without exotic materials, if “building” can be any type of structure (not necessarily a habitable building) and the practical constraints of constructing such a “building” can be ignored, the answer is much taller than you probably think.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: As gandalf61 says, without any specification of "building" it can be nearly anything. Orbital elevators are in a sense 36,000+ km buildings (but made of cables under tension). Presumably the actual question is about molecular materials under compression and with tapering, where the answer still seems to be in the hundreds or thousands of km (depending on assumptions).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273260/2451 and links therein.

Comment: On  Dragon's Egg,  the practical limit was a few mm  until exotic materials could be produced.